# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1000} \frac{e^{-10x}\sin x}{x} \text{d}x$ to within $\pm 10^{-5}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1000} \frac{e^{-10x}\sin x}{x}  \text{d}x$$ to within  $\pm 10^{-5}$.

Comment: Done! Your turn.

Comment: @DikshaBansal: Welcome to MSE! It helps to format using MathJax (see FAQ). I updated your question. Also, it helps if you show what you have done, that you tried and your thoughts. Regards

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Calculators/Software can't do that for you? As stated, this question is liable to be closed as "Not a Real Question". Please do check out the FAQ (you will find a link at the top).

Comment: @FixedPoint Why reintroduce the asterisk as multiplication sign? It's *wrong*! I won't start an edit war, so I am not going to touch it again.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I didn't touch the multiplication asterisk. I just fixed the fraction. I agree it looks stupid so I'll change it to a dot.

Comment: @FixedPoint: Why even put a dot?

Comment: @Aryabhata Just for clarification, to stay close to what the OP intended.

Comment: @FixedPoint: No need to :-) Just make it look nice and mathematical :-)

Comment: Done! Sorry guys, I think our edits just conflicted/overlapped. I certainly didn't intend an edit war.

Comment: **Hint**: $|\frac{\sin x}{x}| < 1$ and

$$|\int_{1000}^{\infty} e^{-10x}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx| < \int_{1000}^{\infty} e^{-10x} dx = \frac{e^{-10000}}{10} \sim 1.135\times 10^{-4344}$$
is really really small.

Comment: @FixedPoint: I see. Sorry if I get a bit carried away. But I thought the system warned you about conflicting edits?

Answer (score 3):

The exponential term practically begs us to replace the upper limit of the integral with $\infty$. In that case, the integral may be evaluated via Parseval's Theorem.

$$f(x) = e^{-10 x}\, \theta(x) \implies \hat{f}(k) = \frac{1}{10-i k}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \implies \hat{g}(k) = \begin{cases} \\ \pi & |k| < 1\\0 & |k|>1\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \: e^{-10 x}\,\frac{\sin{x}}{x} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-1}^1 dk \: \frac{\pi}{10-i k}\\ &= \frac{i}{2}\left [ \log{(10-i)} - \log{(10+i)}\right ]\\ &= \arctan{\frac{1}{10}} \\ &\approx 0.0996687 \end{align}$$

This is equal to the numerical approximation of the stated integral to far more than the number of places provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking more about this, one don't need to approximate the integral by sending the upper limit to $\infty$ nor know how to evaluate the integral over $[0,\infty)$.

For $x > 0$, $|\frac{\sin x}{x}| < 1$ and $e^{-x}$ drops off to $0$ very quickly.
If we cutoff the integral at $1$ instead of $1000$. The error:

$$\left|\int_{1}^{1000} e^{-10x} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx\right| < \int_{1}^{1000} e^{-10x} dx < \frac{e^{-10}}{10} \sim 4.54 \times 10^{-6}$$

itself is small enough. For $x \in [0,1]$, one can Taylor expand $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as:

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}$$

If one chop off the term for $k \ge 4$, we have:

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x} - (1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!})\right| < 1/9! + 1/11! + \cdots \sim 2.781\times 10^{-6}$$

This implies

$$\begin{align}&\left|\int_{0}^{1} e^{-10x}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx - \int_{0}^{1}e^{-10x}(1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!}) dx \right|\\ <& 2.781\times 10^{-6} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-10x} dx\\ \sim & 2.781 \times 10^{-7}\end{align}$$

Within an accuracy of $10^{-5}$, we have:

$$\int_0^{1000} e^{-10x} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \sim \int_0^1 e^{-10x} (1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!}) dx \\= \frac{20930417}{210000000}-\frac{50976061}{630000000} e^{-10} \sim 0.099665$$